# Use Excel VBA to save workbook as .csv.gpg

Tags: vba, csv, gnupg, ansi

I am currently using excel vba to save workbooks as csv files. Now I want to encrypt the workbook and save the workbook as .csv.gpg (ANSI). Any suggestions on how to do that?

```
With NewBook
.SaveAs Filename:=(Location + Name), FileFormat:=xlCSV
End With
```

Comment: `.SaveAs "C:\myFolder\myBook.csv.gpg"`?

Comment: A CSV file is just plain text, so you can encrypt the file after writing it out from Excel.

Comment: File can't be processed downstream. Think that is because the file is not being encoded as ANSI. Any thoughts?